# Async API Request New

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, webforms

I am trying to make an API call in an ASP.NET web form. The request works fine in Console, but async requests are timing out and not working. Please advise.

Console App Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

using Newegg.Marketplace.SDK;
using Newegg.Marketplace.SDK.Base;
using Newegg.Marketplace.SDK.DataFeed;
using Newegg.Marketplace.SDK.DataFeed.Model;
using Newegg.Marketplace.SDK.Item;
using Newegg.Marketplace.SDK.Item.Model;
using Newegg.Marketplace.SDK.Order;
using Newegg.Marketplace.SDK.Order.Model;
using Newegg.Marketplace.SDK.Other;
using Newegg.Marketplace.SDK.Other.Model;
using Newegg.Marketplace.SDK.Report.Model;
using Newegg.Marketplace.SDK.RMA;
using Newegg.Marketplace.SDK.RMA.Model;
using Newegg.Marketplace.SDK.Seller;
using Newegg.Marketplace.SDK.Seller.Model;
using Newegg.Marketplace.SDK.Shipping.Model;

namespace example
{
    public class Demo
    {
        private OrderCall ordercall;
        private ItemCall itemCall;
        private SellerCall sellerCall;
        private DatafeedCall datafeedCall;
        private RMACall rmaCall;
        private ShippingCall shippingCall;
        private ReportCall reportCall;
        private OtherCall otherCall;

        public Demo()
        {
            //Construct an APIConfig with SellerID,  APIKey(Authorization) and SecretKey.
            APIConfig config = new APIConfig("****", "********************************", "********-****-****-****-************");
            // or load the config file to get it.
            //APIConfig config = APIConfig.FromJsonFile("setting.json");

            //Create a APIClient with the config
            APIClient client = new APIClient(config);

            //Create the Api Call object with he client.
            ordercall = new OrderCall(client);
            itemCall = new ItemCall(client);
            sellerCall = new SellerCall(client);
            datafeedCall = new DatafeedCall(client);
            rmaCall = new RMACall(client);
            shippingCall = new ShippingCall(client);
            reportCall = new ReportCall(client);
            otherCall = new OtherCall(client);
        }


        public void GetOrderStatus()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("GetOrderStatus");

            // Send your request and get response
            var orderstatus = ordercall.GetOrderStatus("105137040").Result;

            // Use the data pre you business
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("There order status is {0}.", orderstatus.OrderStatusName));
        }
}
```

My ASP.NET code

```
public partial class HomePage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private OrderCall orderCall;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(LoadSomeData));
            }

        }

        public async Task LoadSomeData()
        {
            string path = @"C:\Users\*****\source\repos\Orders\Settings\setting.json";

          
            APIConfig config = APIConfig.FromJsonFile(path);
            APIClient client = new APIClient(config);

            orderCall = new OrderCall(client);

            try
            {
                var orderstatus = await orderCall.GetOrderStatus("105137040");
                Debug.Write(orderstatus.OrderStatusName);
                Connect.BackColor = Color.Green;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Connect.BackColor = Color.Red;
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

        }

    }
       
}
```

After using my code, the page freezes and eventually times out. The returned object is also null or returns an error.

Comment: Do you have `Async = "true"` set in the `Page` directive in the .aspx file?

Comment: @devNull yes I do

Comment: If devNull's suggestion doesn't work, try to change your await orderCall.GetOrderStatus("105137040") to await orderCall.GetOrderStatus("105137040").ConfigureAwait(false).

Comment: @Kuroiyatsu I tried that. For something reason it throws an Invalid Value Exception. I've also tried loading and it says there is a problem with data at the root level.